# NSPredicate and filtering

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have a `NSMutableArray` called comboData which I am trying to filter out:

```
  NSMutableArray * filteredVersion = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSPredicate    *predicate        = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id >= %d AND id <= %d",1,7];
  [filteredVersion setArray: [comboData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                          predicate]
                        ];
```

I get an `unknown selector` error message

```
  [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa966350
```

at the second line.
What I (anew) missing ?

**[EDIT]**

The comboData is as follow (printed out in the debug area)

```
combo data (
    {
    id = 1;
    label = "A";
    name = '';

},
    {
    id = 2;
    label = "B";
    name = '';

},
```

Comment: Please add an exception breakpoint to find the line that is crashing.

Comment: It is the last one, when I call setArray...

Comment: Please can you show the code for the setArray function.

Comment: It is a standard iOS method of NSMytableArray.h

Comment: What are the objects contained in the comboData array?

Comment: Can you show where you create the comboData array. It is probably something to do with what is inside it.

Comment: I load it from a DB. But I assure that is an array of Dict: i see it in the log

Comment: Cool, so show us it. In particular, does it have a key "id" if so what is the type of this object? ... Object! Of course! OK, putting an answer...

Comment: See my answer. The values for "id" are not ints. They are NSNumbers. You have to treat them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so your array `comboData` is filled with `NSDictionaries`.

An `NSDictionary` can only contain objects.

It looks like the key `id` references a number and so it will be a `NSNumber`.

In your predicate you are treating it as an int.

You will need something like this...

```
// erm... not sure. Can you not just use a comparator?
// NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id >= %d AND id <= %d",1,7];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSNumber *idNumber = dictionary[@"id"];

    return [idNumber intValue] >= 1 && [idNumber intValue] <= 7;
}];
```

This should work.

Just use this instead of your current predicate.

Comment: Great! Is that the simplest solution?

Comment: I think so. I don't think `predicateWithFormat` is very powerful for working with objects. Not 100% certain though.

Comment: Unfortunately I have an anonymous crash when I execute you code: this is my implementation:
double maxDistance=0.0003;
                NSPredicate *nearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSDictionary *bindings) {
                    NSNumber *idNumber = dictionary[@"Distance"];
                    return [idNumber doubleValue] < maxDistance;
                }];
                [jsonCloudArray filterUsingPredicate:nearPredicate];
                NSLog(@"le nuvole vicine sono %@", jsonCloudArray);